# Check if value is between two column's values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new with php and sql, so I'm having some problems with a task.

**The task is:** I have a db with 3 columns, having a city name, minValue and maxValue. This db must have about 200 rows, like this:

> | COL 1      | COL 2    | COL 3|
>
> | São Paulo |    65000000 | 65050000|
>
> | Brasilia  |  69000000 | 65090000|

**I must receive a value, and check if it's between the values from COL 2 and COL 3, and this must be checked for every row in the table.**

For now I'm getting the value from post, and doing the following:

```
 <body>
  <?php 
  $cep = $_POST["cep"];
  $connect = mysqli_connect("--db settings--");
  $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tabela_cep WHERE $cep BETWEEN `COL 2` AND `COL 3`");
  $dados= mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    $cep_lenght = strlen((string)$cep);
    if($cep_lenght == 7) {
        $cep = (string)$cep;
        $cep = "0" . $cep;
    }else{
        return;
    }
    if($dados) {
    echo "<p>The value <strong>$cep</strong> is valid !</p>";
  }else {
    echo "<p>The value <strong>$cep</strong> is invalid !</p>";
  }
     ?>
```

The problem is: every value I submit is being considered as valid.

I'm studying PHP right now,but I'm getting from the basics, and as I need to solve this as soon as possible, I need your help.. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: seeing that both columns are probably varchar `$cep` is most likely a string also. that needs to be quoted. Also add `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`. Your `between`  won't work, because you can't use strings to check "between". Only integers and times. Read up on it http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Please don't use `"$sql_injection_exploit"`, instead use parameterized queries.

Comment: Did you consider trying > and < instead of between operator?

Comment: `00000` and `01999` are not supported by an `int` type. MySQL will recognize `BETWEEN 2 and '3'` but not `BETWEEN 2 and '003'`. as per the manual `SELECT 2 BETWEEN 2 AND 'x-3';
        -> 0` unless it's CAST. Question is also, what is being passed in `$cep`?

Comment: @Fred The values are unreal, but the values are 8 digits numbers. And I set the COL 2 and COL 3 to int,so the between should be working,shouldn't?

Comment: *"the values are unreal"* - so... `00000` and `01999` aren't real values, correct? If `01999` is a real value, does it really start and others with a zero?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I meant that those aren't the values on the db.The values are more like  68500000 | 68504000 ,they don't start with 0 like the examples. Sorry for the misunderstanding..

Comment: @o11c I'll consider this from now, thanks :)

Comment: Please update your question with the correct values then. Other people visiting the question may also see that as being questionable. Noticed the upvotes I've gotten on previous comments in regards to that? ;-) if your columns are indeed `int` then I can't see this failing. What results are you looking to get? and again, what value is being assigned/passed in `$cep`? Plus this `if($produto) {` I doubt you want to use that. You'd want to use a `while` loop then echo the results with the related row.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Edited the answer as recommended. And the value can be in a really big range (we're talking about 8 digits numbers). And I need to get this value, which can be 02966020 for example, and then check in any row the value is between the values in the COL 2 and COL 3

Comment: scratch the last part of my previous comment. I tested your code with success. You still haven't told me what `$cep` is passing by as. I can't help you anymore than I already have, so now someone gave you an answer, you will need to take it up with them. I have a working solution, but I doubt it will match what your table schema is. First column varchar and the others are `int`. Good luck.

Comment: ok I see a leading zero `02966020` and you said *"they don't start with 0 like the examples."* you're just adding more confusion. Sorry, but I can't help anymore. See the answer below. oh, still nothing on `$cep`. Here... Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thank you for all the answers and tips, first I'll make this work without considering that the $cep,that is an integer, might start with 0. I'll also work on error handling/reporting and study about SQL injection right now, Once again,thanks for the attention.

Comment: Seeing that your input starts or may start with a zero, that will fail. You need to prevent it from happening and is most likely the root of the problem. If you have no choice, then you'll need to CAST that to an integer. That's the only way you'll make this work, if a leading zero must be used, or stands to be used. My tests were conclusive. Plus, if you have one row that has 2 columns, holding numbers 1 for COL1 and 1000 COL2, but then another that has 1000 for COL1 and 1 for COL2, that will present a problem; and depending on which operator you will use. That's the best I can come up with.

Comment: and you're welcome. You could also trim off leading zero(s), which is another option, and detecting if a leading zero is present in the input. Good luck, am sure you'll find your solution, *cheers*.

Comment: If you want to cast your POST input to an integer with someone entering a leading zero, it's quite simple. For example: If `$cep = $_POST["cep"];` and someone enters 010, it will be invalid. However, if using `$cep = (int)$_POST['number'];` then that will be cast as an integer 10. Even if they enter 00010 it will still be considered as 10. There you have it, an easy way to CAST to integer ;-) you can also use `$cep= ltrim($cep, '0');` to trim off zeros from the left.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey, it worked!  I passed all the values in the db to integers, and forced the $cep to be a integer too. So, when the value given don't start with 0, it works normally. When the value starts with 0, either the $cep and the db values will have the 0 removed, in other words, will work anyway. Then, to echo the same value given by the user in the form, I made a simple way to CAST the cep to string and add a '0' before. Thank you, I'll update the question and start care about the others problems with my code.

Comment: That's great news, glad to hear it, *cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_cep WHERE $cep > `COL 2` AND $cep < `COL 3`
```

Also as has been said, you are not sanitizing your inputs.  Make sure you do that to avoid SQL injection.